I cannot connect to the Postgres database located on the server
I created a database on the Railway app service. Created a postgres database on it but when I try to join it using the provided credentials I get an error
error when I try to run the project locally
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "artem"] [n/a]

error when I try to run the project on the server
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"] [n/a]

I use the following spring boot application properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://roundhouse.proxy.rlwy.net:28209/railway
spring.datasource.name=postgres
spring.datasource.password=somePass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=ture

Moreover, if you use the built-in IntellijIDEA utility to connect to the database, everything connects perfectly


the error messages are saying you are trying to login using usernames artem and root even though your user is defined as postgres?

the error messages are stating it is a simple password authentication failure, if you use the correct username and password it will work

@JAsgarov If this is a login and password problem, then why can I successfully log into the database using the intellijIDEA utility?

cause you are using a different login and password perhaps?

@JAsgarov Unfortunately, no, because I copied all the data from the ones provided to me by the service. And it doesn't work with the same passwords

it is a deterministic system - if it says that username/password is wrong then it is because you have used either a different URL OR different username OR different password

The usernames in your errors don't match the username in your properties. Which can only mean those properties are being ignored and you are using something different then the Spring Boot provide datasource. One thing is that there is a wrong property spring.datasource.name doesn't exist you probably wanted to use spring.datasource.username instead.

@M.Deinum Thank you very much, really, the problem was that user was written instead of username
